# Convert List of Map.Entry to LinkedHashMap

Tags: java, stream, java-stream

I have a List and I need to convert it to the Map but with the same order of keys, so I need to convert to the LinkedHashMap. I need something like that:

```
list.stream().collect(Collectors.toMap(Map.Entry::getKey, Map.Entry::getValue));
```

but with concrete type of map, like :

```
list.stream().collect(Collectors.toCollection(LinkedHashMap::new))
```

Is it possible to combine both variants above?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Yes, just use the `Collectors.toMap` variant that includes a merge function and a map supplier:

```
<T, K, U, M extends Map<K, U>> Collector<T, ?, M> java.util.stream.Collectors.toMap(Function<? super T, ? extends K> keyMapper, Function<? super T, ? extends U> valueMapper, BinaryOperator<U> mergeFunction, Supplier<M> mapSupplier)
```

Using a simple merge function (that selects the first value) will look like this:

```
LinkedHashMap<KeyType,ValueType> map =
    list.stream().collect(Collectors.toMap(Map.Entry::getKey, 
                                           Map.Entry::getValue,
                                           (v1,v2)->v1,
                                           LinkedHashMap::new));
```

Comment: But instead of `(v1,v2)->v1`, better use `(v1,v2) -> { throw new AssertionError("keys should already be unique"); }`

Answer (score 0):

the Streams collect method has a signature that allows for you to pass a collection supplier, an accumulator, and a combiner.

```
    <R> R collect(Supplier<R> supplier,
                  BiConsumer<R, ? super T> accumulator,
                  BiConsumer<R, R> combiner);
```

In this case you could use this with

```
Map existing; // keys match list values.
list.stream.collect(
    Maps::newLinkedHashMap,
    (map, item) -> map.put(item, existing.get(item),
    (l, r) -> { throw new IllegalStateException("combiner not needed here");}
);
```